# How to select an entity based on it's association, like a WHERE IN query in raw SQL

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Say I have an entity like:

```
Parent
```

And it has a collection of children:

```
Parent.Children
```

I'm trying to get all parents where the children.Id is in a list.

```
Session.QueryOver<Parent>( () => parentAlias)
.JoinAlias( () => pareintAlias.Children, () => childrenAlias)
.WHereResitrictionOn(childrenAlias.Id).IsIn(childrenList)
.List<Parent>();
```

But the above doesn't work, it says the index reference is out of bounds or something similiar.

**Update**

My tables:

Parent
-Id

Children
-parentId

My entity has a HasMany collection linking to the Children table.

So the query would be something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Parents p
    INNER JOIN Children c ON (c.parentID = p.id)
WHERE c.id in (SELECT id from Children WHERE id in (....) )
```

I have a List of Children:

```
List<Children> childrenList;
```

Comment: You may get a better if you gave us some sql that we could convert.

Comment: @Ash updated with table layout and query that I want.

Comment: Doh' didn't see that this was an nHibernate question. In linq, If you are using fairly simple logic to determine the list of children then It's something like:

    var selectedParents = from c in Context.Children
                          where c.Proper1 == DesiredProperty1
                          Select c.Parent;

Comment: @PeterLaCombJr. this wouldnt do the OP's query even if he used LINQ, he wants Contain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: need to specify `<Child>`

using QueryOver

```
var results = Session.QueryOver<Parent>()
    .JoinQueryOver<Child>(parent => parent.Children)
        .WHereResitrictionOn(child => child.Id).IsIn(childrenList)
    .List<Parent>();
```

or using LINQ

```
var results = (from parent in Session.Query<Parent>()
               from child in parent.Children
               where child.Id.IsIn(childrenList)
               select parent).List();
```

Comment: in your QueryOver example, do I need to create aliases?  child.Id doesn't seem to resolve.

Comment: normally JoinQueryOver should change the type for all following calls to the childtype